# How to verify whether input 2 can be constructed using words in input 1 using Java?

Tags: java, loops, random, boolean

Let's say we are given two text inputs. "input1" is a page in a novel. "input 2" is a random sentence "How do you do?". I need to verify whether this input 2 can be constructed using words in input1. Only solution I could come up with for this problem is like this.

**step 0:** create a boolean flag and set is value to true.

**step1:** Split first input into tokens and store the number of times each word occurs in a hashmap.

**step2:**  Split second input into tokens and iterate through the tokens.

**step3:** Inside the loop, check whether the current token exists in the map. If not, set the boolean flag to false and exit the loop. If yes, check the value of the entry returned from Map. If it is zero, set the boolean flag to false and exit the loop. If the value is one or more, decrease it by 1 and continue the loop.

**step4**: Once the loop is done, return the value of the boolean flag.

As you can see, step1 and step 3 could take a long time if the inputs are big. What are the alternative methods to solve this problem which can have better run time?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are falling prey to "Premature Optimization" (look it up).  Your approach is sound, implement something and see how it performs.  You'll be surprised at how fast a Java `Map` can be, and splitting into tokens (words) won't be time-consuming.

Worry about optimizing only after you've determined that you have a performance problem, and then optimize only the code that your profiling efforts have identified as problematic.  Any other approach is a waste of *your* time, which is a lot more expensive than a few trillion CPU cycles.

EDIT in light of the extra information in the comment:

One improvement could be made if you knew the target phrase (the "random sentence" in the question) was always a lot shorter than the main text.   Invert the solution and put the target words in the `Map` and use a similar algorithm while scanning the main text.  Your search space would be smaller and you could stop as soon as you found enough words in the main text.

However, this is faster only if the target phrase is consistently shorter than the main text, which wasn't explicitly specified.  For text sizes in the order-of-magnitude specified (one page and one sentence) the difference in performance would barely be measurable.

Comment: that is very sound advice and you are absolutely right about premature optimization. I was asked this question in an interview and the interviewer was adamant that they is a better solution for this problem. Just trying to find out what it is... (I forgot to ask him at the end of the interview)

Comment: It would have been helpful if you included all the pertinent information in your original question.  I've edited my answer to give one alternative solution.